# how to configure Windows Service Program in azure portal (PaaS)

Tags: azure

We have installed the windows service program in azure virtual machine. After installing the windows service that has been displayed in Services.msc - this is working fine without any issues.

But while we migrating the web application to Azure PaaS , how to configure the windows service in azure portal. Kindly provide the step by step process to achieve this.

Otherwise please provide if we have any alternate method to achieve this in azure PaaS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Windows Service" Paas on Azure, you need to migrate your Code to Azure Functions or Azure Appservice Webjobs.

Read more here https://mariankostal.com/2021/01/24/convert-windows-service-to-azure-function/